# Stiff Telescopic Arm

Tags: photography

I purchased a selfie stick for my girlfriend as she is always trying to get the best angle.

Due to me being cheap i bought one for a few pounds, but the telescopic arm is very stiff.

How can i make the telescope easier to extend, but without making it easily twisted.

[image: Selfie Stick]

Comment: I think that an image would be very helpful here. Would you mind posting one?

Comment: Probably just apply some lube

Comment: @michaelpri I have now added an image.

Comment: @CRABOLO I have some WD40, but I'm worried it will make the arm spin with the weight of the phone.

Comment: The risk of make it not so stiff, is getting it too loose. But just be careful when applying the lube, and you shouldn't have any problem. Another option is to manually work it quite a few times to see if that loosens it somehow. Some new thingies get a little looser when being worked a little.

Comment: I sprayed a very small amount of WD40 down one edge which seemed to work perfectly.

Comment: @Terry, if the WD40 worked out for you, please feel free to post as answer and selfaccept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This remains on the 'unanswered' list so I'll answer it in order to change that.

As Terry says. The answer is to spray a very small amount of WD40 down one edge.

Comment: Urgh.

While WD40 will lubricate it, it's better to use an actual lubricant and not a water displacement tool.